# How to display grid for main axis and not for twinx?

Tags: plot, julia

Here is a MWE:

- main plot with yticks and `grid=true`
- twinx plot with yticks and `grid=false`

this leads to no ygrid being displayed at all.

```
using Plots

# Generate some data
x = 1:10
y1 = rand(10)
y2 = rand(10) .* 100  # Scale y2 to be on a different scale

# Plot with twin y-axis
plot(x, y1, color=:blue, label="y1", yticks=[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8], grid=true)
# Set grid=true for main plot
plot!(twinx(), x, y2, color=:red, label="y2", yticks=true, grid=false, legend=:topleft)
# Set grid=false for twinx plot
```

[image: MWE]

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a bug, the workaround consist in adding the lines manually.

```
using Plots

# Generate some data
x = 1:10
y1 = rand(10)
y2 = rand(10) .* 100  # Scale y2 to be on a different scale

# Plot with twin y-axis
plot(x, y1, color=:blue, label="y1", yticks=[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8], grid=true)

# Manually add grid lines for the main plot
for ytick in [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]
    hline!([ytick], color=:black, alpha=0.2, lw=0.5, label=false)
end

# twinx plot
plot!(twinx(), x, y2, color=:red, label="y2", yticks=true, grid=false)
```

[image: workaround]